# Binding secondary function within fullPage and Vuejs

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

Using VueJS, receiving error `app.js:11754Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).bind is not a function`. I wan't to call the isLoaded function once triggered inside the fullPage. I know i need to bind 'this' to get things working however Its not working so far. Where should the bind(this) be placed?

```
        one_page: function () {
        $('#dosbcn').fullpage({
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
            afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                //using index
                if(index == 2){
                    console.log('second page here');
                    this.isLoaded(); // Vue function to be called if the index is equal to 2.
                }
            }
        });
    },
    isLoaded: function () {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes I get those issues when a function or line wasn't ended with a `;`.  Are your files being included/combined together server side?

Comment: This issue was declaring the 'this' before the full page. like this... `var that = this;` then using `that` like ==> `that.isLoaded`

Comment: Post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a vue method inside a function I needed to declare this outside of the targeted function like so:

```
        one_page: function () {
        var that = this; // declare this as that here...
        $('#dosbcn').fullpage({
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
            afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                //using index
                if(index == 2){
                    that.isLoaded();
                }
            }
        });
    },
    isLoaded: function () {
        console.log('yep yep')
    }
```